# svn checkout shows only directory structure, how to get all files?

Tags: eclipse, svn

How to checkout directory structure and all files?

I'm using Eclipse and all I got is just the directory structure.

Comment: Do you use _Subversive_ or _Subclipse_? Which connector do you use: _SVNKit_ or _JavaHL_? Could you reproduce this problem with a public SVN repository and share the URL?

Comment: thanks, I just fixed it , did a build/update revision graph cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed it , did a build/update revision graph cache